# Jewish tunes similar to non-Jewish ones

Tags: music, gentiles

What are some examples of a traditional Jewish song that bears a strong similarity to a non-Jewish melody?

(I am wording this question carefully to exclude recent Jewish take-offs of secular music; and to avoid unproductive discussion about which version came first.)

Comment: Does singing dror Yikra to the tune of the beach boys count as "recent Jewish take-offs" or "traditional Jewish song"?

Comment: @avi - "recent Jewish take-offs" for sure. I haven't heard that one, so it can't be *too* traditional. :)

Comment: I'm sure you have heard it. Listen to the song Sloop John b.  It's normally sung as Seudat Shlishit. http://www.zemirotdatabase.org/view_song.php?id=53#rec

Comment: @avi - Nope, never heard Dror Yikra sung to that tune. I guess we live in different parts of town... :)

Comment: A rabbi of mine told me the following in the name of Rabbi Nachman from Breslov: Only on shabbat do gentile melodies become holy.  Mah she'ein ken regarding Jewish songs that are holy the entire week all seven days including shabbat.

Comment: How about [Yehuda!'s **Umacha**](http://www.yehuda.org/albums/ohyeru/webaudio/Umacha.mp3) and [Blind Melon's **No Rain**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3qVPNONdF58&ob=av2e)?

Comment: Should we close as too broad and opinion-based? Who knows how many answers there are, and it's really up to the listener to decide if they're similar enough to count.

Comment: How would anyone know, if you're [not allowed to listen to music](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/5794/9682)?

Answer (score 8):

Two popular Chabad Chassidic niggunim were both adapted from French songs:

- "[Napoleon's March](http://chabad.info/php/audio.php?action=playsong&id=211)," taken from the marching tune used by the French army during their invasion of Russia in 1812. (R' Shneur Zalman is said to have heard the tune and said that it represents the ultimate victory of "our" - the Russian - side, as indeed occurred.)
- "[Ha'aderes Veha'emunah](http://www.chabad.info/php/audio.php?action=playsong&id=683)," set in 1973 by some French chassidim to the tune of La Marseillaise. (Interestingly, a few months later the French government formally altered the tune - their national anthem - somewhat. In a talk of his in 1991, the Lubavitcher Rebbe zt"l observed that evidently, on a spiritual level, they realized that the original tune no longer "belonged" to them.)

Comment: Any links to these?

Comment: http://chabad.info/php/audio.php?action=playsong&id=211 and http://www.chabad.info/php/audio.php?action=playsong&id=683, respectively.

Answer (score 5):

A few examples that come to mind are:

1) Maoz Tzur, which is said to be [an adaptation from an old German folk-song](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ma%27oz_Tzur#Tune)

2) The Kaliver niggun Sol A Kokosh Mar, which was [taken from a shepherd's song](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=active&client=firefox-a&hs=BlV&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&q=kaliver+sol+a+kokosh+shepherd&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=)

3) The Purim song "Mishenichnas Adar," [taken](http://parsha.blogspot.com/2008/03/mishenichnas-adar-pick-bale-of-cotton.html) from "Pick a Bale of Cotton."

Comment: It seems that this tune of Mishenichnas Adar was actually taken from an Irish folk song (which is where Pick a Bale of Cotton probably orginiates), since British Jews were singing this tune long before they would have heard Pick a Bale of Cotton.

Answer (score 4):

Well, the traditional Ashkenazic "Maoz Tzur" would be a great candidate since it is in perfect cadence and key with "[Deck the Halls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deck_the_Halls)". The problem is that Maoz Tzur (the Ashkenazic tune) is actually a knock-off of a German folk tune! See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ma%27oz_Tzur#Tune) and [here](http://www.chazzanut.com/media/maoz.html).
As per the wiki article it actually was chosen by Luther sr"y for one of his hymns. What is still amazing is the similarity between Maoz Tzur, being of German origin and Deck the Halls, being of Welsh origin.

Comment: Man, Dave you jumped me while I was working on the source links!

Comment: Well, I did have a bit of a head start :)

Answer (score 4):

Hatikva is based on an old Italian folk tune "[La Mantovana](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pq-9hPiQn-A)"

And of course the wedding favorites of "Asher bara sasson v'simcha":"[I come from a land down under](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DNT7uZf7lew)" and "yiddin": "[Ghengis Khan](http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=5329218840884525228&q=dschingis+khan#)"

Answer (score 4):

The Syrian and Jerusalem sephardic traditions for chazzanut are based heavily on arab songs. One can look in many Sephardic song books and see the name of the arabic song that the melody comes from.

R' Ovadia Yosef defends this practice in a teshuva in Yechave Da'at vol 2 #5, and says  "על ערבים בתוכה תלינו כנרותינו"  -- on the *Arabs* within it, we hung our lyres (i.e. our musical tradition).

Answer (score 2):

A great resource for traditional Jewish music (with lots of information on history, influences): [Jewish Music Research Centre](http://www.jewish-music.huji.ac.il/)

Comment: I can't access that link

Comment: @follick: Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

One tune of Psalm 150 is based on Allahu by Nusrat Fateh Ali Kahn

Answer (score 2):

1) See [here](http://onthemainline.blogspot.com/search?q=Najara), where apparently Kah Ribon is meant to be sung to the tune of some Arab Melody entitled "Ya Rabi Shalim Sha'ilmi.

Answer (score 2):

El Galil is really [Ya Galmil](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dW-m1bkz6eo) from [Farid Al Atrash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farid_al-Atrash).

Comment: Can you link to the Arab version? (Youtube, perhaps.)

Comment: done...........15 character rule

Comment: thanks! I'll listen to it as soon as I can. My friends and I always argue about how a certain part is sung (בזכותו עמד עולם...) cant wait to hear how he does it.

Comment: sure it is! And I was right!! This is so awesome thank you so so much!

Comment: @vram no prob. My bad, it is in there. I just haven't heard the song in a while.

Answer (score 1):

[Mi Armiya Admora](http://chabad.info/newvideo/video.php?id=2250) - A communist march adapted by R' Ben Tzion Shemtov

[Lyuba Brtsi Lyuba](http://video.chabad.info/newvideo/video.php?id=1348) - a Cossack song sung by the mashpia R' Mendel Futerfas.

Comment: Any links to these?