# Listening to Ambient Music

Tags: halacha, gentiles, music

Is there anything wrong about listening to [Ambient Music](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambient_music) produced by Non-Jews (with no lyrics or vocals and certainly no issue of Kol Isha.) The reason for listening to it is in order to relax or for pure enjoyment. Is it better not to because it's been produced by non-Jews (i.e. they perhaps lack the proper "intention" behind the production of the music.) Perhaps this only not permitted from a "spiritual" or "hashkafic" point of view.

I use the term "Ambient Music" as somewhat general to describe any sort of slow-style, relaxing music. I would ask the same question in regards to Classical Music as well if someone wishes to address this in an answer.

I realize a [similar question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5794/sources-for-listening-to-not-listening-to-non-jewish-music) was already addressed. However I'd like to specifically ask in the case of "Ambient Music" where there are no lyrics involved and is a localized genre which is difficult to say that this is "non-Jewish" music.

Comment: How is this not covered in the previous question and its answers? (Not that being covered in previous answers is really relevant.)

Answer (score 3):

HaRav Yaakov Hilel says there is no way to say it's Asur Meikar Hadin but any music created by non-Jews or Jewish Reshaim should not be listened to (Wayashov Hayam).

Comment: I presume Al Pi HaSod it would be a problem.

Comment: What is the problem al pi sod?

Comment: @Yehoshua עמוק עמוק מי ידענו

Comment: So how does anyway know then at all!?

Comment: @Yehoshua I meant that I don't know, and I don't remember him bringing a reason.

Answer (score 2):

There is no prohibition against 'non-Jewish' music per se. See [this](http://beismedrash.blogspot.com/2012/06/secular-music.html) blog post.