# Can one listen to Christian songs?

Tags: halacha

Is it permissible to listen to Christian songs (for example: Pierpont's "Jingle Bells" Schubert's "Ave Maria" and secret garden's "You Raise Me Up"? )
Is it permissible to sing them?
Is it permissible to listen to instrumental versions of them? 
Is it permissible to sing the melodies without the words?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5794/sources-for-listening-to-not-listening-to-non-jewish-music/11974#11974