# What is the perception of Dance in Judaism?

Tags: music, performance-entertainment, dance

What is the perception on **dance** (of any kind) from the perspective of Judaism? or there are some kind of restrictions?

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/125575/music-and-judaism

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: What do you mean by perception? Are you asking if it is allowed? Alone? In groups? Same-sex groups? Mixed? Together with music? Jewish music? Asking a more detailed question is most likely to give you the answer you are looking for

Comment: @mbloch Any kind of dance. if it is allowed or restricted or forbidden.

Comment: Sefardim are not allowed to dance on yom tov, gezeira against boneh for instruments. Exception is made for Simchat Torah when the mitzva is to dance. Dancing is an expression of joy, and dancing in a circle is a thing: https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1966560/jewish/Why-Jews-Dance-in-Circles.htm

Comment: @Oud then it is best to [edit] your question so it is self-standing. It might get closed otherwise

Comment: @mbloch my question clearly states that it is about dance of any kind. it may be ballet or classical or pop of zumba or folk or whatever

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Saba said you should get up every half hour and sing Na Nach Nachma Nachman meUman and dance.  It's a big mitzvah to be constantly happy. The happiness needs to reach from one's head, pervade into his heart and reach his feet and brought to action.

So, it's allowed and recommended, barring certain restrictions like mixed (men and women) dancing publicly.

**Edit/Corrections:** As I looked for a source I received this from a friend, who said this is now printed in a certain new book. But this statement is known among Breslevers.

> ב"ה סבא אמר - יש דיבור מאברהם בר נחמן שצריכים לרקוד כל יום חצי שעה, אתה רוקד?
> זכרונות של יעקב שילוח
> נ נח

My translation: Saba (Yisroel Odesser z"l) said, "There's a statement from Avraham bar Nachman (Goldstein, the Tulchiner Rav) that you need to dance every day a half hour! Bruh do you even dance?! - Memoirs of Yaakov Shiloach*

> /* Yaakov Shiloach was a secular kid living and working in New York, next door to where Saba stayed on one of his visits. Saba befriended him, Saba was well over 80 years old, but he chilled with Yaakov as a regular guy. It would take some time until Yaakov realized who Saba was, but even before that Saba told him that it was inappropriate to wear shorts, at the very least they should be till the knees.
> Na NaCh NaChMa NaChMaN MAyUMaN

Comment: What does the maaseh about Yaakov Shiloach teach us about dancing? It seems entirely superflous to the question asked.

Comment: @יהושעק You may be right but If I were reading this I would want to know some context of who it was said to, as otherwise there doesn't seem to be much info on him; and the context flavored my translation.

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer? It brings the opinion of a very fringe group within a sect of Hasidic Judaism. Even if it is correct, there needs to be a better answer here as well.

Comment: @ezra Why, can a "fringe group"'s answer not be accepted? You can say "there needs to be a 'mainstream' answer as well" but fringes are  essential to Judaism and sometimes where the ikar miswa is at.

Comment: The na nach song was invented by someone who lied about a letter coming down from heaven to him. This question is about Judaism not someone's Jewish inspired imagination so this doesn't even answer the question let alone qualify for being the accepted answer.

Comment: @Dude more like someone who was lied to