# Tune for Avinu Malkeinu has non-Jewish source?

Tags: tefilla, gentiles, music

Some synagogues do not sing the last stanza of Avinu Malkeinu to [this](http://cbimilwaukeeinfo.org/data/HHDMusic/AvinuMalkeinu.mp3) tune out of belief that it has a non-Jewish, possibly Christian, source.

Is this tune in fact not Jewish?

Note: even if the tune has a non Jewish source, it may originally have been Jewish similar to the Yigdal tune [which apparently was originally Jewish](http://www.oztorah.com/2008/11/a-christian-hymn-the-yigdal-tune-ask-the-rabbi/).

---

[Related discussion](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2405/jewish-tunes-similar-to-non-jewish-ones/2418#2418)

Comment: Many chasidic tunes have non Jewish sources. Tbe famous kalev one 'solo kokosh' in Hungarian is a case in point.

Comment: https://www.torah4blind.org/niggun/n-4.htm 7. One of his favorite songs is "_Szol a Kakas Mar_" - "The rooster is already crowing." The English translation comes from Avraham Yaakov Finkel's book, _The Great Chasidic Masters_, pp. 94-95.

Comment: @preferred So what? The question is about the origins of the tune, not the halachot of nonjewish tunes

Comment: @preferred some poskim dustinguish between nonjewish religious sources which are problematic vs nonjewish popular culture  sources which are acceptable

Comment: @preferred thanks for the detailed reference. Rav SY Zevin has that story in Sippurei Cgassudim as well.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14319/discussion-between-yoni-and-preferred)

Comment: @preferred Your link was added to question. Thanks!

Comment: @DoubleAA is this on topic?

Comment: @mevaqesh the question is obviously addressing the potential issue of singing non jewish tunes and asking if that potential issue exists with this tune.

Comment: @Yoni First of all it is not at all clear that asking background information to determine weather something is muttar is on topic. E.g. "is the Verrückt in Schlitterbahn safe to ride, and therefore muttar, or does it violate ushmartem" second of all, I am not aware of any halakhic problem with singing non-Jewish tunes.

Comment: Hopefully, that shul is also not singing the common *En K'Elokeinu* tune for the same reason. Don't get me started on what non-Jewish tunes have infiltrated wedding / "Simcha" music lately. "Sunshine of your love" is still part of *Ketyzad Merakdim*,  apparently....